# Stream audio/video from remote server with php

Tags: php, stream, remote-server

Its a while im looking for a right way to stream mp3,mp4 and other formats from remote server with php.
The thing is I have two servers A and B which the website is on the server A.
Because of having lots of large files I need to be able to use remote servers and for securing our links we use php to serve media files. The problem is when the file is on server B and we want to play it with the php file on server A it first gets downloaded to server A and then starts to play.
Any one knows whats the right way to stream files from remote server directly with php ?

Comment: You've got to give the client a URL that points directly to server B. It's got nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: our links are like https://my-site.com/play/435efdtfgrt because we generate stats and we check the login and all with this php system. when we give the server B link to this php file it first loads the file on server A and then plays it thats the problem

Comment: Yes I understand that -- but if you don't want the stream to go through server A, then the client will have to connect directly to server B. There's not really any way around that.

Comment: You could reverse proxy from server A to server B. That would allow you to stream without having to wait for (or store) a complete download, but you'd still be bouncing all that bandwidth through server A, twice.

Comment: What about streaming trough ftp ? we connect server A to B with ftp and read from there that will be the same ?

Comment: Bandwidth is not a problem we are on a unmetered service but what about the memory usage and all and how we can do this reverse proxy ? we use nginx as the web server

Comment: Google "nginx reverse proxy"